Advanced peak "blocks" analysis
I have very basic knowledge in programming and I have been using some tips I found here, and for that thank you in advance.
Moving on to the problem, I am analyzing data from optical sensors that are measuring the extension caused to the pavement by vehicles.
The simplest way I found to treat the raw file, since every 10 minutes 300.000 lines are generated in xlsx format, is a filtering of the noise with a kind of zscore algorithm. This algorithm will detect the most prominent peaks, but not all the ones I need. My Idea:

Take the indices of these peaks that were detected and treat each one of them as a "block/passage" and after that, analyze each block individually.
From the peak initially found, I wanted to define that I needed to collect the two seconds before and three seconds after, because this way the entire temporal space relative to each vehicle/passage would already be covered.

After the algorithm collected these 5 seconds, I needed:

the count of peaks/axes of the vehicle
the maximum values ​​of each peak
the increase in extension relative to the resting point (existing in the 2 seconds before the first peak).

I'm trying to dig in chatgpt but I always reach a dead end :/
Ill leave the algorithm im currently using for preliminary analysis below.
Thank you so much
So Ive tried many approaches,including Savitzky filter to smooth the data and then find the peaks based on the derivative but the strategy that is giving me the best results is to calculate the moving average and standard deviation, and then define the peak based on that, adjusting the treshold, lag and influence of peaks.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_excel('2023_09_28_16_59_06.xlsx')


lag = 500
influence = 0.5
threshold = 10


def find_peak_indices(signal, lag, influence, threshold):
peak_indices = []  
peaks = []  
processed_signal = [] 
processed_signal.append(signal[:lag])
avg_list = []
sd_list = []

for index in range(lag, len(signal)):
y = signal[index]
avg_list.append(np.mean(processed_signal[-lag:]))
sd_list.append(np.std(processed_signal[-lag:]))

    
if abs(y - avg_list[-1]) > sd_list[-1] * threshold:
peak_indices.append(index)
peaks.append(signal[index])  

   
if index > 0:
adjusted_value = (influence * y) + ((1 - influence) * processed_signal[-1])
else:
adjusted_value = (influence * y)  # No previous value, take y as is
        
processed_signal = np.append(processed_signal, [adjusted_value])
    
processed_signal = processed_signal[1:]

return peak_indices, peaks


signal = df[df.columns[16]]


peak_indices, peak_values = find_peak_indices(signal, lag, influence, threshold)


moving_avg = df[df.columns[16]].rolling(window=lag).mean()
std_dev = df[df.columns[16]].rolling(window=lag).std()


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))  


plt.plot(signal, label='Signal')
plt.plot(moving_avg, color='red', label='Moving Average')
plt.title('Signal with Moving Average')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


plt.plot(std_dev, color='green', label='Standard Deviation')
plt.title('Standard Deviation')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


plt.plot(signal, label='Signal')
plt.scatter(peak_indices, peak_values, color='red', label='Peaks')
plt.title('Signal with Peaks Detected') 
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


print("Picos encontrados:")
`for i in range(len(peak_indices)):`
`print("Índice:", peak_indices[i], "- Valor do pico:", peak_values[i])`


If you are looking for prominent peaks, I would use an existing peak finding algorithm such as scipy.signal.find_peaks. Pass the data through it multiple times to filter for more prominent peaks:
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

def get_filtered_peaks(data: pd.Series, iterations: int = None):
    """
    obtain prominent peaks by continuously filtering peak data
    will always filter at least once
    data: A signal containing peaks
    iteration: optional arg for explicit number of filter passes
               if unset, iterations will scale with data size 
               
    """
    if iterations is None:
        iterations = len(data) // 100000 # change this however you like 
    i = 1
    while True:
        data = find_peaks(data, distance=1, width=0)
        if i >= iterations:
            break
        i += 1
    return data


Select data within a timeframe around your peaks (assuming index is a timestamp in):
def get_time_blocks(data, peaks, window) -> List[DataFrame]:
    """
    Note: assumes index is set to a timestamp
    """
    blocks = []
    for idx, _ in peaks.iterrows:
        blocks.append(df.loc[
            (df.index >= peak.index - window) &
            (df.index <= peak.index + window) 
        ])
    return blocks


Hello, I tried to integrate the suggestions you gave me into the original code and in a file with just one vehicle with of 5 axes. The algorithm only detected several points defined as a peak on the first axis, and none on the others :/

Then you should look very closely at the documentation of scipy.signal.find_peaks, especially the examples near the bottom of the page which cover filtering techniques. I'm pretty sure it has the functionality you need.

Thank you Brian, i'll see what I can find!

Hi, I was able to use the find_peaks function successfully and retrieve information about the peaks detected. I still have some problems with the width due to the noise I sometimes have in the data.
